# How to make a bash script wait till a pendrive is mounted?

Tags: linux, scripting, mount, udev

I have a bash script which has a line `cd /run/media/Username/121C-E137/` this script is triggered as soon as the pen-drive is recognized by the CPU but this line should be executed only after the mounting process is complete. As of now what happens is this line is executed before the pen-drive is mounted and returns an error the directory is invalid.

Comment: Depends on your system. If you use `systemd`, you can write a `udev` rule using `SYSTEMD_WANTS`... It's documented in `man systemd.device`.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to let your script do the mounting. What is causing the mounting now?

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution would be to have the script periodically check for the directory, and only proceed once it's there:

```
PENDRIVE='/run/media/Username/121C-E137'
while [ ! -d "$PENDRIVE" ]; do
    sleep 10
done

cd $PENDRIVE
...
```

Comment: This sleep command is suspending the mounting as well the Pen-drive never gets mounted now until i comment the newly added lines in the script .

Comment: You should use the `wait` command instead of the `sleep` command.

Answer (score 1):

The following will check that the pendrive directory is mounted by checking if it appears in `/proc/mounts`

```
pendrive='/run/media/Username/121C-E137'
while ! grep -q -s "$pendrive" /proc/mounts; do
        sleep 10
done
cd "$pendrive"
```

If you need to account for the uncommon possibility mounts like `~/run/media/Username/121C-E137` that aren't what you want, then you could modify that to:

```
pendrive='/run/media/Username/121C-E137'
while ! grep -s "$pendrive" /proc/mounts | awk '{print $2}' | grep -q -s -x "$pendrive"; do
        sleep 10
done
cd "$pendrive"
```